# Wkhtmltopdf black and white pdf only

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

How can i generate a pdf with wkhtmltopdf which is only black and white?

I couldn't find anything in the docs https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

By printing provided can only print the pdf as black and white, if there is no RGB color profile in it.

Comment: Are you wanting purely black and white, or grayscale?

Comment: Not sure. How would I do b&w and how grayscale?

Comment: Don't know about b&w, but for grayscale there is a global option `-g` (or `--grayscale`) mentioned in the docs

Comment: I habe the (same?) problem that black text is not black but rgb 0,0,0 + grey 0 instead of just black. Binary: h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64.

Comment: @garyh `-g` option change the rgb color in grayscale, fine. But, I try for this https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html where if I can remove background color it is well to me.